# Calculate minutes in specific period

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet which has employee working times, listed as Sat-In and Sat-Out for a specific date. The employee shift spans several ours and each "In-Out" period is recorded as a separate line which means the time between the  Sat-Out and the next Sat-In means the employee is on a break. I also calculate the time, in minutes of each "sitting" period.

What I can't seem to figure out is how to add a formula which takes the data and further refines it in this manner:
1. I have a core period of 1030-1530, as an example, which is the busy time and requires the maximum employee coverage. The shifts of employees generally spans this core, but in some cases their shift may start or end in the core.
2. I want to calculate how many minutes the employee worked within the core only. I can obviously do this manually using the data, but a formula would be preferred, if possible.
3. As an example, if a person sat-in at 1445 and sat-out at 1545, the core time calculation would be 45 minutes (1445-1530).

I've attached a snapshot of the data to help my explanation.

FYI - the information is pulled from a database as JSON data and converted to excel. I'm not very familiar with JavaScript, but if someone knows a way to do it programatically, I'm willing to give it a try and learn.

Thanks!

![excel]: https://photos.app.goo.gl/dRSTE72CXNa18RzP8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In below example I've used: `=MAX(0,MIN($O$2,H2)-MAX($O$1,G2))`, and formatted like [mm].

[image]

Comment: Perfect!! Thank you

Comment: If this answers your question please consider marking it as answered.

Answer (score 0):

In Excel, units are days, so if you want to calculate the amount of minutes between two timestamps, you need to subtract both and multiply the differencee by `24*60` (being the amount of minutes in one day).

E.g. You start working at `09:07` (cell `B2`), and finish at `18:07` (cell `B3`), having a 45-minutes break. Then the time you worked in minutes, is:

```
=(B3-B2)*24*60-45
```

Make sure the cell formatting is correct (general), you'll get : 495.